# $_SESSION: Undefined Index

Tags: php, html, session

I'm creating a booking site for meeting rooms.
I have done the sql query to search for free rooms according to the time and date chosen.
This is working. I display the free rooms (in a while loop) in cards with datas from the query.

```
<?php           
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo '<main role="main">
    <div class="card-columns">';
    require_once 'connexion_BD.php';

  $res_date = $_POST['res_date'];
  $res_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($res_date));
  $res_horaire_id = $_POST['res_horaire'];
  $_SESSION['res_date'] = $_POST['res_date'];
  $_SESSION['res_horaire'] = $_POST['res_horaire'];

  $sql = "SELECT sal_nom, sal_nb_place, sal_notes
            FROM salle
            WHERE sal_id NOT IN (SELECT res_sal_id FROM reservation WHERE res_date = :res_date AND res_horaire_id = :res_horaire_id)";
  $requete = $db->prepare($sql);

  $requete->bindValue(':res_date', $res_date);
  $requete->bindValue(':res_horaire_id', $res_horaire_id);
  $requete->execute();
  $i=0;
  while ($row = $requete->fetch()) {
    $tab_sal_nom[0+$i] = $row['sal_nom'];
    $tab_sal_nb_place[0+$i] = $row['sal_nb_place'];
    $tab_sal_notes[0+$i] = $row['sal_notes'];
    ?>
    <div class="card bg-light">
        <img class="card-img-top" <?php echo 'src="img/salle_reunion_'. rand(1, 8) .'.jpg"' ?> alt="Salle de réunion">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Salle <?php echo $tab_sal_nom[0+$i]; ?></h5>
            <p class="card-text">Salle disposant de <?php echo $tab_sal_nb_place[0+$i]; ?> places.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Informations de salle : <?php echo $tab_sal_notes[0+$i]; ?></small></p>
            <form action="confirm_resa.php" method="POST">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary float-right" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" name=<?php echo '"reserver_'.$tab_sal_nom[0+$i].'"'?> type="submit">Réserver</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php 
  $i = $i + 1; 
  }
} 
?>
```

Now here's my problem, I want to know which room name the user choose to store the info in a `$_SESSION['sal_choix']`, so, I look at the submit button named `<?php echo '"reserver_'.$tab_sal_nom[0+$i].'"'?>` (equals to reserver_Daum, reserver_Majorelle, reserver_Galle, reserver_Corbin etc...)

My idea was to look with some if:

```
if (isset($_POST['reserver_Daum'])) $_SESSION['sal_choix'] = "Daum";
elseif (isset($_POST['reserver_Galle'])) $_SESSION['sal_choix'] = "Galle";
etc...
```

But that's not working, cause in the confirm_resa.php, `$_SESSION['sal_choix']` is: undefined index

It's not a session problem because two other : `$_SESSION['res_date']` and `$_SESSION['res_horaire']` are sets.

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the `if(isset($_POST[]))` but I can't see it...
help pls!

Comment: shouldn't you be calling session_start() before you look for any session variables

Comment: The `button` element allows to specify a submission value different from the actual button content. Don’t use x buttons with x different names, use x buttons with _one_ common name, and x different values.

Comment: I include a header_member.php at the top which contain a session_start(), so I don't think, it's not working only for $_SESSION['sal_choix']

Comment: Like this ?                                                                                                     
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary float-right" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" name="reserver" value=<?php echo '"'.$tab_sal_nom[0+$i].'"'; ?> type="submit">Réserver</button>                                                                                       I tried changing the if like this :                                                                                                    if (isset($_POST['reserver'])) $_SESSION['sal_choix'] = $_POST['reserver']; not working